# Android app mp3 media player seek bar not working with some MP3 songs, but it's works with some other mp3

Tags: android, server, streaming, android-mediaplayer, mp3

I am working on an Android App which play MP3 songs. MP3 player seek bar is not working with some MP3 songs but it works with some MP3.

All MP3 streaming from server. All MP3 files are some.

1. Is it server side issue? Do I need something on server?
2. Is it MP3 file issue? are there any difference between in MP3 files?
3. Do I need any other file format?
4. Should I change my hosting? shared to VPS?
5. Are there any other android media player library for MP3?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it server side issue? Do I need something on server?

Could be.  You didn't mention what protocol you're using, so I'll assume HTTP.  In the ideal case, the client should be able to make ranged requests.  Not all HTTP servers support these, which could explain the difference in behavior.

> Is it MP3 file issue? are there any difference between in MP3 files?

Regular MP3 files don't contain any sort of timestamp information.  It's not technically a seekable format.  Players work by calculating bitrate and estimating where to seek into the file in bytes.  Then, they re-sync to the stream and continue playback.

> Do I need any other file format?

You can put MP3 audio in another container which *is* seekable.

> Should I change my hosting? shared to VPS?

That's not the root of your problem, no, but your server does need to support range requests.

> Are there any other android media player library for MP3?

Use the built-in system code.  It's well-optimized and in some cases hardware accelerated.

Comment: Hello Brad,

Thank you so much for the help.

Now it's working with HTTPS.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Shashank If this answer helps you, consider checking the "accepted answer" check mark next to it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Brad I am facing issue with SeekBar can you please help me... here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692981/android-music-seekbar-is-not-working-idle